# Save Button Not attached to the Right InfoWindow, Google Map

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, save

After adding a delete function and adding my markers into an array the save button/ save function is no longer attached to the right infowindow on my google map.

If I open two infowindows, enter the info in both, then click save on the first one I opened it will update the last infowindow created with "You submitted" and it will save it twice.  I tried a few different things based on different stack overflow posts including adding an iterator around the initialization of my infowindow and also adding an external function for adding a marker, but this did not work. I also made sure my global variables (like map) are declared before initializing. I am a nube that has been struggling for days.

I'm sure the issue surrounds my confusion about how the infowindow is attached to the markers in the array. My code is in the snippet below.

```js
        var markers = [];
        var uniqueId = 1;
        var marker;
        var infowindow;
        var map;
        var html;


        function initialize() {

          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {
              lat: 48.591130,
              lng: -119.682349
            },

            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: ['roadmap']
            }
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

          //Attach click event handler to the map.
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

            //Determine the location where the user has clicked.
            var location = e.latLng;

            //Create a marker and placed it on the map.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map,
            });


            //Set unique id
            marker.id = uniqueId;
            uniqueId++;
            markers.push(marker);


            //Attach click event handler to the marker.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
              html = "<p style='color:#173e43;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; width:150pxs; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom:4px' >Add A Comment</p>" +
                "<table>" +
                "<tr><td>Issue/Idea:</td> <td> <textarea rows='1' cols='26'  id='name' style='height: 30px; width:150px' name='reply'></textarea></td> </tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address' style='width:150px'/></td> </tr>" +
                "</td></tr>";

              html += "<tr><td><input type = 'button' value = 'Delete' onclick = 'DeleteMarker(" + marker.id + ");' value = 'Delete' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button'  value='Submit' onclick='saveData(" + marker.id + ")'/></td></tr>";

              infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html
              });

              infowindow.setContent(html);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            //Add marker to the array.
            markers.push(marker);

          });

        };


        function DeleteMarker(id) {
          //Find and remove the marker from the Array
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].id == id) {
              //Remove the marker from Map                  
              markers[i].setMap(null);

              //Remove the marker from array.
              markers.splice(i, 1);
              return;
            }
          }
        };

        function saveData(id) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].id == id) {

              var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
              var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
              var latlng = markers[i].getPosition();


              var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                 "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();

              downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
                if (responseCode == 200 && data.length >= 1) {
                  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added. Contents: name=" + name +", address=" + address+ " latlng=" +latlng;
                }
              });

              infowindow.setContent("You submitted Contents: name=" + name +", address=" + address+ " latlng=" +latlng);
            }
          }
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
          }; 

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);

          function doNothing() {}

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 490px"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with your fiddle `Uncaught ReferenceError: saveData is not defined`.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell, `saveData` is doing the correct thing.  Why do you think it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks geocodezip, I cleaned up the code snippet to make it more readable.  

My problem happens if someone opens more then one infowindow.  Say I place a marker on Walla Walla, open the window and enter info into it, then place a second marker on Sunshine Valley.  If I go back to the Walla Walla marker (without closing any of the windows) and hit submit, the window above Sunshine Valley will say "You submitted Contents: name= Walla Walla".   On top of that it will save the same Walla Walla information twice in my database.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: IDs must be unique, getElementById() will always return the same element, no matter how much elements inside a document share the same ID-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I moved the push statement so that it is pushing the marker to the array after I declare the infowindow.  This stopped the save function from saving the html contents multiple times. So the save is working great now, the only problem is my ability to update the right infowindow with the message "You submitted..."
It is still just updating the last infowindow I opened with that message.

```js
        var markers = [];
        var uniqueId = 1;
        var marker;
        var infowindow;
        var map;
        var html;


        function initialize() {

          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: {
              lat: 48.591130,
              lng: -119.682349
            },

            mapTypeControlOptions: {
              mapTypeIds: ['roadmap']
            }
          };

          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

          //Attach click event handler to the map.
          google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {

            //Determine the location where the user has clicked.
            var location = e.latLng;

            //Create a marker and placed it on the map.
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: location,
              map: map,
            });


            //Set unique id
            marker.id = uniqueId;
            uniqueId++;
           

            //Attach click event handler to the marker.
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
              html = "<p style='color:#173e43;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;text-align:center; width:150pxs; margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom:4px' >Add A Comment</p>" +
                "<table>" +
                "<tr><td>Issue/Idea:</td> <td> <textarea rows='1' cols='26'  id='name' style='height: 30px; width:150px' name='reply'></textarea></td> </tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Address:</td> <td><input type='text' id='address' style='width:150px'/></td> </tr>" +
                "</td></tr>";

              html += "<tr><td><input type = 'button' value = 'Delete' onclick = 'DeleteMarker(" + marker.id + ");' value = 'Delete' /></td>" +
                "<td><input type='button'  value='Submit' onclick='saveData(" + marker.id + ")'/></td></tr>";

              infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: html
              });

              infowindow.setContent(html);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

            //Add marker to the array.
            markers.push(marker);

          });

        };


        function DeleteMarker(id) {
          //Find and remove the marker from the Array
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].id == id) {
              //Remove the marker from Map                  
              markers[i].setMap(null);

              //Remove the marker from array.
              markers.splice(i, 1);
              return;
            }
          }
        };

        function saveData(id) {
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            if (markers[i].id == id) {

              var name = escape(document.getElementById("name").value);
              var address = escape(document.getElementById("address").value);
              var latlng = markers[i].getPosition();


              var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?name=" + name + "&address=" + address +
                 "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng();

              downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
                if (responseCode == 200 && data.length >= 1) {
                  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Location added. Contents: name=" + name +", address=" + address+ " latlng=" +latlng;
                }
              });

              infowindow.setContent("You submitted Contents: name=" + name +", address=" + address+ " latlng=" +latlng);
            }
          }
        }

        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
          var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

          request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4) {
              request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
              callback(request.responseText, request.status);
            }
          }; 

          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.send(null);

          function doNothing() {}

        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 490px"></div>
<div id="message"></div>
```